# how to handle authentication in django for multiple apps and functionality

Tags: django, django-views

I know authentication should be global. all apps in a django project should serve the same purpose, but I am in a situation where I need to restrict some parts of the app to some users.

I have a screen that allows you to access different app functionality

.i.e

- personal spending
- to-do list
- e-mail scheduler/ report scheduler

users should be able to see all apps, click on them, log in and then access different functionalities based on who they are.

the views should also be different when they're an admin or just a simple user.

how can this be achieved in django?
is it with groups ?

Comment: The django user model has two attributes you could use, `is_staff` and `is_superuser`. If you want more control then groups and permissions should be your choice.